# Using .lower or 'or' in if __ is __ statement causes incorrect if statement flow in python 3.6

Tags: python, if-statement, lowercase

I searched and couldn't seem to find anyone who has had this same issue, although I'm very new to python and there's a great chance it is just user error.

I'm having problems using both 'or' and .lower in an if statement. If i use the code:

```
print('press Y to continue or Q to quit')
end = input()
if end is 'y':
    continue
else:
    break
```

then my code works correctly, although if the user types in a capital Y, the program continues to the else statement, and ends the program. If I use the following code:

```
print('press Y to continue or Q to quit')
end = input()
end = end.lower()
if end is 'y': #I have also tried end.lower() here, removing the line above
    continue
else:
    break
```

The program continues to break with any input. If I print 'end' before the if statement, it returns:

```
<built-in method lower of str object at 0x7fa6b8176f80>
```

I've also tried replacing is with ==, which gives me the same results. Is there a problem with how I'm phrasing my if is statement?

Comment: typo, `end.lower` or `end.lower()`?

Comment: `end = end.lower` stores a bound method object into `end`, something you can call later. You probably wanted `end = end.lower()`, which _calls_ that method, which returns a string, and then stores that string in `end`.

Comment: If this is just a simple typo, that's cool; you can fix it and we can close the question. If you don't understand why `end.lower` doesn't call the method (maybe you came to Python from Ruby, where it would), we can find a duplicate question with an answer that explains it. Just let us know which one is the case.

Comment: Do **not** use `is ` to compare strings. It *happens* to work for single character strings, but you shouldn't rely on that implementation detail.

Comment: Meanwhile, your second problem is completely different; you shouldn't try to cram two questions into one. But it's also got duplicate answers—see the links at [this page](https://sopython.com/canon/22/why-doesn-t-if-x-a-or-b-or-c-do-what-i-expect/).

Comment: I removed the second problem, and fixed the typo. My code did use end.lower(). I thought the second problem might be related, but I realize now it's completely unrelated.

Comment: Ok, this question can be closed. By following juanpa's advice, I changed out is with ==, and it's working correctly now. I guess I had a typo when I tried to use == earlier. Sorry for the bad question!

Comment: What is that continue for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems:

1. You're using `end.lower` instead of `end.lower()`. This means that Python will see the method `str.lower` instead of its result.
2. You use `is` instead of `==`. This forces Python to check if the two are the same object, i.e., in the same physical space on your computer. `==` checks if they have the same value. In general, you pretty much always want `==`.